# Can't get backbone view to respond to events added by this.on()

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I want to listen to event/s in my View, but only after some processing (to be specific, I only what to respond to these events after a successful ajax call - that is all working, it's just this event stuff I can't figure).

Because of this, using the events property isn't going to achieve what I'm after.

I'm new to backbone and am at a loss as to what the problem is with my this.on('click'...) code below (backboneClicked() does not fire).

I have included the events property below as I put this in to test and it fires ourClick(). jqueryClicked() also fires.

Am I missing something really obvious?

I know there are lots of other questions about views not firing events, but I couldn't see anything that matched this question.

Any help appreciated.

```
var InputListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#input-list',

    events: {
        'click input'       : 'ourClick'
    },

    initialize: function(options) {         
        this.$el.click(this.jqueryClicked);

        this.on('click', this.backboneClicked);
    },

    ourClick: function(e) {
        alert('ourClick');
    },

    backboneClicked: function(e) {
        alert('backboneClicked');
    },

    jqueryClicked: function(e) {
        alert('jqueryClicked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.on('click', this.backboneClicked);`

What behavior do you expect this to have? You can't click on a view, it's an object, not a DOM element... Though if you really want to test if it works, try add a `this.trigger('click')` after your line.

Still, I don't get what the point is here. If you're using the `on` method of Backbone, you're usually trying to listen to Backbone events (or custom events), not UI events.

Comment: Thanks Loamhoof. I'm new to backbone and still gaining confidence in javascript. You're right. I was getting DOM events and API events mixed up. What I want to do is actually listen for the change event on some input elements, but only after some other conditions are met (i.e., after a successful ajax call. There is a good explanation of DOM events and API events and Views here http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#events-and-views along with example code.